# How to remove remaining traces of a detached database from a server?

Tags: sql-server, attach

I had a database `Coderr` that I no longer wanted. Unfortunately, I detached it instead of dropping it. Now I'm seeing traces of it pop up in SSMS dialogs:

[image]

I'd like to remove this (and any others that may be lurking).

I tried `DROP DATABASE [Coderr]`, but I got this error:

> Cannot drop the database 'coderr', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

I found [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183984/63237), but the T-SQL over there is a bit over my head and I'm nervous running it since I don't know whether it applies to my scenario.

How can I permanently clean all references to this old, unwanted database from my server? Will it be possible to do so, or am I stuck with the consequences of my goof-up?

Comment: How about somebody engage in some actual constructive criticism, instead of just rudely downvoting and voting to close? (It's rude because you didn't say why.) You don't think I'd like to improve this question? How can I improve it when all you do is throw drive-by downvotes, without giving so much as a HINT on how to fix the problem? This is just about the worst aspect of the StackExchange properties, in my opinion. How is a newcomer supposed to improve when all he gets are silent, anonymous gut punches? Yes, you. I'm talking to you.

Comment: What I would do is to attach the database back, or even restore it from the last backup, and then go for the  `drop database coderr`.

Comment: about the downvote or harsh comments you get, don't let this petty things interfere in your mood, carry on adding your questions here.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Thank you also for the kind words—I'll take 'em to heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to remove this (and any others that may be lurking).
>
> I tried DROP DATABASE [Coderr], but I got this error:
>
> > Cannot drop the database 'coderr', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Once you detach the database, it technically no longer exists in your instance of SQL Server (despite the file existing physically on disk still).

If I was you, your safest best would probably be to just re-attach it, then properly drop it. The scripts in the [linked post's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183986/150011) are rather safe to run after you've re-attached the database.

The first set of scripts just backups the database, closes any open connections to it, and then drops it. Just make sure you replace `[db_name]` with `Coderr`. John Eisbrener's code from that answer for historical reference:

```
-- Use master db to ensure you don't have an active connection to the db you wish to affect
USE [master]
GO

-- This will kill any active transactions, but will force the database into a Read-Only state
ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET READ_ONLY WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

BACKUP DATABASE [db_name] -- Fill in more options here or use the UI to take a backup if you chooose
GO

-- This will kick out all connections from the database allowing you to drop it.
ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

-- Drop the database (which automatically removes the files from the OS)
DROP DATABASE [db_name]
GO
```

The second set of scripts isn't modifying anything, rather it just gets some meta-data about Logins that were referencing the database you just dropped. John's code, once again for historical reference:

```
DECLARE @ExecString NVARCHAR (4000)

-- Create Empty Table in a very lazy manner
SELECT  name, principal_id, CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(128)) as database_name
INTO ##tmp_AllDBUsers
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE 1 = 2

-- Declare Cursor to iterate through all DBs on the instance
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR
FOR
        SELECT name
        FROM sys .databases    

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR (128)
OPEN dbCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor
INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @ExecString = 
    'USE [' + @name + '];
    INSERT INTO ##tmp_AllDBUsers
    SELECT sp.name, sp.principal_id, DB_NAME()
    FROM sys.server_principals sp INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp
        ON sp.sid = dp.sid'

    EXEC(@ExecString)

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor
    INTO @name
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor because you've finished traversing all it's data
CLOSE dbCursor
DEALLOCATE dbCursor

-- Show all logins that do not belong to a server-level role nor have access to any databases
SELECT sp.*
FROM sys.server_principals sp LEFT JOIN ##tmp_AllDBUsers adu
    ON sp.principal_id = adu.principal_id
WHERE adu.principal_id IS NULL
    AND sp.principal_id NOT IN (SELECT member_principal_id
                            FROM sys.server_role_members)
    AND TYPE IN ('S', 'U', 'G')

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE ##tmp_AllDBUsers
```

You should be safe running both, so long as you put the correct database name in the first set of scripts.

---

> How about somebody engage in some actual constructive criticism, instead of just rudely downvoting and voting to close?

Unfortunately *them's the breaks* when using a free answer service, but I wouldn't take it personally. If I were to speculate, whoever downvoted you might've found your question trivial, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: `> I wouldn't take it personally`

Sounds like you've been down this road before  Thanks for the tip, it worked! I restored the files from backup, reattached them, and was able to drop the database. (Not sure why I didn't think of that simple solution, but oh well...)

Comment: @InteXX "*Sounds like you've been down this road before*" - Yep lol. No prob! Glad you're squared away.

Comment: In more ways than one.